# Issue with GIN Index large data set

Tags: postgresql

I am doing an experiment on GIN Index for Jsonb type data.
till I am having 500K rows in a table, GIN Index is working, however when I increase the data to 50Million rows in a table. The GIN Index gets created however explain analysis doesn't seem to consider the Indexes working.

```
postgres=# \d users
                              Table "public.users"
  Column   |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |              Default
-----------+---------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------
 _id       | integer |           | not null | nextval('users__id_seq'::regclass)
 id        | integer |           | not null |
 attribute | integer |           | not null |
 value     | jsonb   |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (_id)
    "user_value_gin" gin (value)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "users_attribute_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (attribute) REFERENCES attribute(id)

=======================================

postgres=# explain analyze select * from users where value @> '{"v": "Rahul"}'::jsonb;
                                                             QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather  (cost=1000.00..1017776.57 rows=897059 width=70) (actual time=880.003..23596.085 rows=913446 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   ->  Parallel Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..927070.67 rows=373775 width=70) (actual time=451.196..22468.458 rows=304482 loops=3)
         Filter: (value @> '{"v": "Rahul"}'::jsonb)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 16362185
 Planning Time: 105.326 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 6
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 502.947 ms, Inlining 676.053 ms, Optimization 560.960 ms, Emission 94.573 ms, Total 1834.533 ms
 Execution Time: 24099.549 ms
(12 rows)
```

My question is that is there any limitation Postgres has on GIN Index?

if yes what is the possible resolution/design change is appropriate to overcome this problem if my requirement is to have approximately 50Billion rows in a table.

Regards
Praveen

Answer (score 1):

You are retrieving nearly 2% of the table.  It is not obvious that using an index is the fastest way to do that.

If you want to force it to use the index, you can `set enable_seqscan=off` and it will probably use the index then

Or, maybe you can pick a more selective thing to search on if all you want to do is see the index work 'on is own'.

Answer (score 0):

Your example query would perform better with `jsonb_path_ops` operator class:

```
CREATE INDEX user_value_gin ON users USING GIN (value jsonb_path_ops);
```

The default `jsonb_ops` operator class indexes each key and value separately. The `jsonb_path_ops` operator class indexes each key value pair. That performs a lot better when, for example, many rows have the same keys. The resulting index is also usually smaller.

The downside of the `jsonb_path_ops` operator class is that it cannot be used with operators `?`, `?|`, `?&` that would require each key to be indexed separately.

My advice is to always go with `jsonb_path_ops` if possible.

You should read [jsonb Indexing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING) on the official documentation for the most up to date information.